# MySQL returns this tufle value (datetime.date(2022, 4, 21),) need to convert "2022-4-21"

Tags: python

Having problems parsing fetch date from mysql. I have example of the code here.

```
    try:
        cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user=config.USER, password=config.PASSWORD, host=config.HOST, database=config.DATABASE)    

    except mysql.connector.Error as err:

        if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
            print("Something is wrong with your user name or password")
        elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
            print("Database does not exist")
        else:
            print(err)
    else:
        cursor = cnx.cursor()
        cur = cnx.cursor( buffered=True , dictionary=True)

        try:
            # cursor.execute("SELECT Error, pair FROM settings WHERE timeframe='15m' AND toggle='1'") #if error disable all from DB
            # myresult = cursor.fetchall()
            cursor.execute("SELECT datetime FROM settings WHERE timeframe='15m' AND toggle='1'")

            start_date = cursor.fetchone()
            print(start_date)
```

(datetime.date(2022, 4, 21),)

Comment: print(date["datetime"])

Comment: You are getting a date back from the database but it appears you want a string. Python can't tell what format you want the string in. Look at the `strftime()` method of `datetime.date`, which will let you specify the format as `"%Y-%m-%d"` to get the YMD string you want.